# How to layer Image Transformer before ConfigMap generator

Tags: kustomize

I have an app that consume a k8s cronjob manifest as a template and I store it as configmap. I want to update the container image in the cronjob template using Kustomize image transformer and generate configmap using Kustomize configmap generator. Here is what I've done:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - cronjob-template-a.yaml
  - cronjob-template-b.yaml
  - cronjob-template-c.yaml

images:
  - name: image/a
    newTag: v1.0.0
  - name: image/b
    newTag: v1.0.0
  - name: image/c
    newTag: v1.0.0

configMapGenerator:
  - name: generated-config-map
    files:
      - cronjob-template-a.yaml
      - cronjob-template-b.yaml
      - cronjob-template-c.yaml
```

When run `kustomize build`, the generated configmap not updated by the image transformer and the cronjob template is being rendered. How to update the cronjob template container image first before generating the configmap? Also how to prevent the cronjob template being rendered?

Comment: The image transformer will not update a ConfigMap. The contents of a ConfigMap are opaque -- they don't follow any specific schema and can't meaningfully be processed using Kustomize like this.

Comment: I know, that is why I want to update my cronjob-templates using image transformer first before process it to configmap-generator